# magento m2epro sync product imported as third party listing

Tags: magento, listings, m2e-pro

I have a magento ecommerce and a correspondig ebay shop. Both are born and grown indipendently from each other but recently I've been tasked to use m2epro to map them, so I imported ebay products as third party listings.
Unfortunately such products, even if mapped to magento products, are not updated regards to price and quantity.
If I try to create a new magento listing with such products and sync them on ebay, a new product is created.
Is there a "right" way to map magento products and third party listings products so that they can work together?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: You have to set up new listings in M2e Pro.